# Sort values that come from different instances of the same class

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the order of the football clubs based on their points. I have created a class that get the values from the internet and process that values to calculate points based on the number of wins, loses and draws. Then I want to write the standings and their data onto a text file in that order. I created 20 different instances for 20 different clubs. However, I don't know what is the best way to sort the order.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CalculateStandings {
    private int matches;
    private int homeWin;
    private int homeDraw;
    private int homeLost;
    private int homeForGoal;
    private int homeAgainstGoal;
    private int awayWin;
    private int awayDraw;
    private int awayLost;
    private int awayForGoal;
    private int awayAgainstGoal;
    private int point;
    private int totalWin;
    private int totalLost;
    private int totalDraw;
    private int totalAgainstGoal;
    private int totalForGoal;


    void getResult(String team_Name) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/eng-england/master/2017-18/1-premierleague-i.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String mydata = input.nextLine();
            if (mydata.contains(team_Name)) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
                String result;
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    matches += 1;
                    result = matcher.group();

                    if (mydata.startsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                        homeForGoal += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(0)));
                        homeAgainstGoal += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(2)));
                    } else if (mydata.endsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                        awayForGoal += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(2)));
                        awayAgainstGoal += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(0)));
                    }

                    if (Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(0))) > Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(2)))) {
                        if (mydata.startsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            point += 3;
                            homeWin += 1;
                        } else if (mydata.endsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            awayLost += 1;
                        }
                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(0))) < Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(result.charAt(2)))) {
                        if (mydata.startsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            homeLost += 1;
                        } else if (mydata.endsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            point += 3;
                            awayWin += 1;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (mydata.startsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            point += 1;
                            homeDraw += 1;
                        } else if (mydata.endsWith("  " + team_Name)) {
                            point += 1;
                            awayDraw += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        totalWin = homeWin + awayWin;
        totalLost = homeLost + awayLost;
        totalDraw = homeDraw + awayDraw;
        totalAgainstGoal = homeAgainstGoal + awayAgainstGoal;
        totalForGoal = homeForGoal + awayForGoal;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
public class Launcher {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CalculateStandings Arsenal = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Tottenham = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings WHam = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings CPalace = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings MU = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings MC = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Everton = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Liv = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings WBAlbion = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings NU = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Stoke_City = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Southampton = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Leicester_City = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Bournemouth = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Watford = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Brighton = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Burnley = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Huddersfield = new CalculateStandings();
    CalculateStandings Swansea = new CalculateStandings();


    Arsenal.getResult("Arsenal FC");
    Tottenham.getResult("Tottenham Hotspur");
    WHam.getResult("West Ham United");
    CPalace.getResult("Crystal Palace");
    MU.getResult("Manchester United");
    MC.getResult("Manchester City");
    Everton.getResult("Everton FC");
    Liv.getResult("Liverpool FC");
    WBAlbion.getResult("West Bromwich Albion");
    NU.getResult("Newcastle United");
    Stoke_City.getResult("Stoke City");
    Southampton.getResult("Southampton FC");
    Leicester_City.getResult("Leicester City");
    Bournemouth.getResult("AFC Bournemouth");
    Watford.getResult("Watford FC");
    Brighton.getResult("Brighton & Hove Albion");
    Burnley.getResult("Burnley FC");
    Huddersfield.getResult("Huddersfield Town");
    Swansea.getResult("Swansea City");

}

}
```

I am thinking about storing the values into several arrays using Getter then sort them using sorting algorithm such as Bubble sort. However, as you can see, the number of instances and the number of fields inside each instances are numerous and write them into the arrays manually using Getter would take too much time. Therefore, I would like to ask you if there is a more optimized approach for this.

Comment: why do you need so many `CalculateStanding` instances when they all do the same thing?

Comment: @Shark Thank you for pointing that out. I now realized I can just create field arrays and for each team, I will give them an index for that array. Then I can use Getter to get the whole array containing data from all teams at once

Answer (score 1):

Use List instead of array. You should also check on the Comparable interface and how to use it. So that later you can use sort method on the List.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
ArrayList < CalculateStandings > footballClubs = new ArrayList < CalculateStandings >();
```

in main class to create array of objects, then use the

```
void add(footballClubName: CalculateStandings)
```

method to add the football clubs instances to the arrayList.

-the next step to force the sorting of the objects is to implement the CalculateStandings class to the Comparable interface by editing the head of the class as this

```
class CalculateStandings implements Comparable < CalculateStandings >
```

and override the implementation of the compareTo method in the body of class to how to compare between to instance of this class. as this

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CalculateStandings o) {
      if(somthing_field(as_your_calculations) > o.somthing_field)
         return 1;
      else if (the_something_field < o.something_field)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
}
```

-then by easy in your main class you can just use the java.util.Collections.
sort(arraylist) to sort it in an increasing order as this

```
java.util.Collections.sort(footballClubs);
```

then if you want it in a decreasing order u may use the for loop to reverse it.

That's all, but i have a side note on your code, you could shorten it and epitomize reading by using instructors with args instead of this no-arg instructors, and use the club name string as your args and in the implementation of the instructor use your calculations without need to use an instance method,

```
public CalculateStandings(String footballClubName) {
   //put your calculations here and assign the class fields.
}
```

just use the instructor to instantiate ones and add them to the array like this

```
footballClubs.add(new CalculateStandings(footballClubName));
```

I wish it help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one single Map with club names as keys and points as values, and you can use lambdas to print out the table, here is an example for sorting clubs based on the points (descending):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private static int rank = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> teams = new HashMap<>(){{
            put("Arsenal", 54);
            put("Chelsea", 44);
            put("Manchester United", 52);
            put("Liverpool", 49);
            put("Tottenham", 50);
        }};

        teams.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted((x,y) -> y.getValue().compareTo(x.getValue()))
                        .forEach(n -> System.out.println(rank++ + ". " + n.getKey() + " with " + n.getValue() + " points."
        ));

    }
}
```

And the output would be:

1. Arsenal with 54 points.
2. Manchester United with 52 points.
3. Tottenham with 50 points.
4. Liverpool with 49 points.
5. Chelsea with 44 points.

If you have any additional questions, just ask me in the comments.